# Import data excel file to PostgreSQL without converting it to csv first?

Tags: excel, postgresql

Is there a way to import data excel file to PostgreSQL without converting it to csv first, if any please help me.

Comment: Yes there is. Save the spreadsheet as XML ([SpreadsheetML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_spreadsheet_example) format) and then use [xmltable function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING). This approach is neutral to the regional settings while export to CSV is not and often (usually) distorts the information.

Comment: Based on what constraints? For example you could load an excel file into Postgresql using SSIS but I'm guessing you only want to use native tools.